# How to fix Angular build fails due to primeng fileupload module p-fileupload tag

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng, primeng-turbotable, bootstrap-file-upload

Error: src/app/shared/fileupload/fileupload.component.html:2:87 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'multiple' since it isn't a known prop
erty of 'p-fileUpload'.

1. If 'p-fileUpload' is an Angular component and it has 'multiple' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-fileUpload' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress t
   his message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

HTML:
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" url="https://www.primefaces.org/cdn/api/upload.php" [multiple]="true" accept="image/*" maxFileSi
ze="1000000">

app-module.ts

imported FileuploadModule

Answer (score 1):

You probably did not correctly import `FileUploadModule`.

Check this `AppModule` example:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'primeng/fileupload'; // <-- import the module
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FileUploadModule, // <-- add this line
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Also, if you have multiple NgModules, make sure to import `FileUploadModule` in the NgModule that declares your component. So your component should be listed in the `declarations` array of the same NgModule.

Your HTML fragment has a few issues as well:

- `maxFileSize` has an extra space
- `maxFileSize` has the type string instead of number
- `p-fileUpload` tag is not closed

Here is a corrected version:

```html
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]"
              url="https://www.primefaces.org/cdn/api/upload.php"
              [multiple]="true"
              accept="image/*"
              [maxFileSize]="1000000"></p-fileUpload>
```

Since Angular 16, components can use self-closing tags:

```js
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]"
              url="https://www.primefaces.org/cdn/api/upload.php"
              [multiple]="true"
              accept="image/*"
              [maxFileSize]="1000000" />
```